# Changing .bashrc after manually installing a tool

Tags: linux, bash

I am working off of a cluster and since I do not have sudo privileges there, I had to *install* a toolkit at a different path `~/bin/tool_kit`. This path now contains the following directories: `bin`, `include` and `lib`. This may be a very newbie question, but what changes do I make to my `.bashrc` so that I am able to use this toolkit.

For example, the `$PATH` variable might be augmented like:
`export PATH = ~/bin/tool_kit/bin:$PATH`. How do I include `lib` and `include`?

Comment: `~/.bashrc` is the wrong file to change -- it's run on every interactive shell's creation, even if it's a child of another interactive shell that already set the environment variables you need. `~/.bash_profile` is the Right Thing to only set environment variables *once*, when you log in.

Comment: Regarding the PATH assignment, do not put spaces around `=`.  Use something like `export PATH=~/"bin/tool_kit/bin:$PATH"

Comment: "right" and "wrong" is relative when it comes to bashrc.

Comment: Anyhow, in many cases you don't need to do *anything* about your `lib` and `include` directories. If the libraries are all static, then a well-behaved program will be using pkgconfig or such to point to their locations when needed.

Comment: (BTW, if you don't want to need to be precise about using the quoting @John1024 suggested, use `$HOME` instead of `~`).

Comment: If the libraries *aren't* static, you may need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but that's only if the software wasn't built with the rpath flag set to the intended install location.

Comment: ...or, to put it differently: "What **exactly** is the behavior you're seeing that makes you think you need to do anything else at all?"

Comment: @n.caillou, I entirely disagree. There are very well-defined best practices for writing robust, reliable shell scripts with predictable behavior on execution; that they're widely ignored doesn't negate their existance.

Comment: 1. I do not have a .bash_profile.
2. How do I know if don't have to worry about lib and include? My .bashrc also has exports to `LIBRARY_PATH`. I assumed `lib` directory would go there.

Comment: @y91, ...do you have a `~/.profile`? (If `~/.bash_profile` doesn't exist, that's one of the later locations looked for).

Comment: @y91, ...re: "how do you know...", well, does your software's install documentation *say* you need to worry about the other locations? Does it fail in a way that implies it can't find content from them? If the answer to both those questions is "no", chances are you don't have to worry.

Comment: @y91, ...btw -- in general, this kind of question is a better fit for http://superuser.com/; StackOverflow's topic is centered around *development* of software, whereas installation (particularly under a home directory) is a matter of usage.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : the lib directory has `.so` files. Aren't these supposed to be dynamic?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , re superuser.com, I thought I am lacking some important and fundamental linux information. That's why came here..

Comment: @y91, "important and fundamental" questions aren't StackOverflow's domain unless they're important and fundamental questions **about writing software**.

Comment: And yes, .so files are dynamic. The other question, though, is if the install location was known at compile time, in which case the build system may (should) have compiled in that location as an rpath -- a runtime path. **If it did**, everything might just work as it is. If it didn't, then you'll want to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include that lib directory.-

Comment: @CharlesDuffy point taken, can we please talk about the `.so` files? :)

Comment: Does it fail because it can't find them? Yes, or no? If "no", then presumably it was compiled with an rpath and you don't need to do anything.

Comment: (I first asked that... six or seven minutes ago now).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , re `rpath`, I did give the current installation path when I did `./configure`

Comment: I don't know if it fails yet, I am compiling a wrapper on top of it and will only know if it works some time later.

Comment: Then if it was a modern autoconf that generated that configure script, and a new gcc &c., you might be set. If it *wasn't*, then you'd want to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH+$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:}$HOME/bin/tool_kit/lib` -- that's a kinda wordy formulation, but it avoids messing things up whether or not there's any LD_LIBRARY_PATH set before the line runs.

Comment: What is the difference between `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` ?

Comment: (btw, `~/opt/tool_kit` might have been a more conventional location; `~/bin` typically stores executable files or links to them, not directories).

Comment: Re: "what's the difference" -- `LIBRARY_PATH` isn't an environment variable name that the Linux dynamic linker pays any attention to, whereas `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is? (`LIBRARY_PATH` is meaningful to gcc, not ld).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I only partly agree. In particular login processes may ignore .profile (though bash considers it), so there are no guarantees to start with. The only way to get a consistent behavior is to define a custom variable and test of it, and that can be done in bashrc as much as elsewhere.

Comment: @n.caillou, fair 'nuff. We're in a bash-tagged question, so I'm considering the INVOCATION section of the bash documentation something it's safe to lean on, but for situations in the rest of the world it's not always so safe.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Re `~/opt/toolkit` , thanks! point taken. I will put the lib path on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` just in case. Thanks for all the info. You can write an answer for this, which I will accept.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, btw, what about `include`. Do we do anything with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bin` is the only location you *definitely* need to do anything with:

```
# using end of the PATH, unless you know you want to override like-named system binaries
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin/tool_kit/bin
```

No `export` is needed here, as the `PATH` variable is already in the environment.

---

If and only if your software didn't compile in a `rpath` pointing to the anticipated runtime library locations, you may also wish to set an LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH+$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:}$HOME/bi‌​n/tool_kit/lib
```

---

`include` files are used only when compiling other software, and are not generally needed at runtime.